# Why did Baz and Josh paint the room white before stealing the safe?

Tags: plot-explanation, animal-kingdom-tv

In [S02E05](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6378404/?ref_=ttep_ep5) of *[Animal Kingdom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5574490/)*, Baz and Josh break into a church's inventory room to steal a safe. Before freeing the safe from the floor, they paint the room white.

Why?

Comment: Perhaps to blow only white-painted part of the floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't paint; it was soundproofing foam. I was confused about that too at first.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you came to know it was soundproofing foam. Preferably with either official sources?